# Form on web page?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on an assignment dealing with forms in HTML and CSS. I'm trying to follow the instructions but my form is coming out really wonky. Any suggestions on how I can fix this? I'd like to learn what I'm doing wrong.

````css
body {
  background-color: #B8DBED;
  font-family: Arial;
}

header {
  background-color: #000033;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 120px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1.5em;
  font-size: 120%;
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
}
nav a {
text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-family: Georgia;
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: 0.25em;
}

h2 {
  color: #3399CC;
  font-family: Georgia;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #CCCCCC;
}

h3 {
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: #000033;
}

dt {
  color: #000033;
}

.resort {
  color: #5C7FA3;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  list-style-type: none;
}

main ul {
  list-style-image: url(marker.gif);
}

footer {
  font-size: 75%;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 190px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

#contact {
  font-size: 90%;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  min-width: 204px;
  background: #90C7E3;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333333;
  border: 1px solid #000033;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF, #90C7E3);
}

main {
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: block;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left: 190px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

#homehero {
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(coast2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin-left: 190px;
}

#trailhero { 
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(trail.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin-left: 190px;
}

#yurthero {
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(yurt.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin-left: 190px;
}

* { 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

a:link {
  color: #5C7FA3;
}

a:visited {
  color: #344873;
}

a:hover {
  color: #A52A2A;
}

header, main, nav, footer, figure, figcaption, aside, section, article { 
  display: block; 
}

#mobile {
  display: none;
}

#desktop {
  display: inline;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 64em) {
  body {
    background: #FFFFFF;
  }

  #wrapper {min-width: 0;
    width: auto;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
  }

  header {
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    padding-left: 0;
    height: auto;
  }

  h1 {
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  }

  main {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  nav {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5em;
  }

  nav li {
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 0.25em;
    padding-bottom: 0.25em;
    padding-left: 0.75em;
    padding-right: 0.75em;
  }

  #homehero {
    margin-left: 0;
    height: 200px;
  }

  #yurthero{
    margin-left: 0;
    height: 200px;
  }

  #trailhero {
    margin-left: 0;
    height: 200px;
  }
  footer {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 37.5em) {
  main { 
    padding-top: 0.1em; 
    padding-bottom: 0.1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    font-size: 90%;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
  }

  nav {
    padding: 0;
  }

  nav li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #330000;
  }

  nav a {
    display: block;
  }

  nav ul { 
    border: 2px solid #000000; 
  }

  #homehero {
    background-image: none;
    height: 0;
  }

  #yurthero {
    background-image: none;
    height: 0;
  }

  #trailhero {
    background-image: none;
    height: 0;
  }

  #mobile {
    display: inline;
  }

  #desktop {
    display: none;
  }

  label { 
    float: none;
    text-align: left; 
  }

  input[type="submit"] { 
    margin-left: 0; 
  }
}

form {
float: left;
display: block;
width: 120px;
padding-right: 200px;
text-align: right;
}

input, textarea {
display: block;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

button {
margin-left: 130px;
}
```
````

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset= "utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <Title>Pacific Trails Resort :: Reservations</Title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="pacific.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1> Pacific Trails Resort </h1>
      <meta name="description" content="Pacific Trails Resort reservations page.">
    </header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>  <li><a href="yurts.html">Yurts</a></li>  
        <li><a href="activities.html">Activities</a></li> 
        <li><a href="reservations.html">Reservations</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <h2>Reservations at Pacific Trails</h2>
      <h3>Contact Us Today!</h3>
      <form name="reservations" method="post" action="http://webdevbasics.net/scripts/pacific.php">
        <label for="myFName">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="myFName" id="myFName">
        <label for="myLName">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="myLName" id="myLName">
        <label for="myEmail">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="myEmail" id="myEmail" size="35">
        <label for="myPhone">Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="tel" name="myPhone" id="myPhone" maxlength="12">
        <label for="myComments">Comments:</label>
        <textarea name="myComments" id="myComments" rows="2" columns="30"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>

      <div id="contact">
        <span class="resort">Pacific Trails Resort</span> <br>
        12010 Pacific Trails Road <br>
        Zephyr, CA 95555 <br>
        <br>
        <a id="mobile" href="tel:888-555-5555">888-555-5555</a> <br>
        <span id="desktop">888-555-5555</span>
        <br>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
      Copyright © 2018 Pacific Trails Resort<br>
      <a href="mailto:e.sween12@gmail.com">e.sween12@gmail.com</a>
      </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've attached some images of how it's supposed to look. Any suggestions would help. Thanks[image][image]

Comment: You could use table to style your form like <tr><td>Label</td><td>input</td></tr>.

Comment: Remove the float attribute applied to the form.

Answer (score 0):

As @JSKIM mentioned in the comments, you just need to remove `float: left` from your `<form>` elements styling. With `float: left`, the text or inline elements will wrap around it. After removing `float`, the content after the form will appear underneath (or next) like it appears in the normal flow.

When you use [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) on an element, it's removed from the normal flow of the page.

```css
body {
  background-color: #B8DBED;
  font-family: Arial;
}

header {
  background-color: #000033;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 120px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1.5em;
  font-size: 120%;
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
}
nav a {
text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-family: Georgia;
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: 0.25em;
}

h2 {
  color: #3399CC;
  font-family: Georgia;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #CCCCCC;
}

h3 {
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: #000033;
}

dt {
  color: #000033;
}

.resort {
  color: #5C7FA3;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  list-style-type: none;
}

main ul {
  list-style-image: url(marker.gif);
}

footer {
  font-size: 75%;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 190px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

#contact {
  font-size: 90%;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  min-width: 204px;
  background: #90C7E3;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333333;
  border: 1px solid #000033;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF, #90C7E3);
}

main {
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: block;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left: 190px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

#homehero {
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(coast2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin-left: 190px;
}

#trailhero { 
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(trail.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin-left: 190px;
}

#yurthero {
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(yurt.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin-left: 190px;
}

* { 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

a:link {
  color: #5C7FA3;
}

a:visited {
  color: #344873;
}

a:hover {
  color: #A52A2A;
}

header, main, nav, footer, figure, figcaption, aside, section, article { 
  display: block; 
}

#mobile {
  display: none;
}

#desktop {
  display: inline;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 64em) {
  body {
    background: #FFFFFF;
  }

  #wrapper {min-width: 0;
    width: auto;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
  }

  header {
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    padding-left: 0;
    height: auto;
  }

  h1 {
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  }

  main {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  nav {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5em;
  }

  nav li {
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 0.25em;
    padding-bottom: 0.25em;
    padding-left: 0.75em;
    padding-right: 0.75em;
  }

  #homehero {
    margin-left: 0;
    height: 200px;
  }

  #yurthero{
    margin-left: 0;
    height: 200px;
  }

  #trailhero {
    margin-left: 0;
    height: 200px;
  }
  footer {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 37.5em) {
  main { 
    padding-top: 0.1em; 
    padding-bottom: 0.1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    font-size: 90%;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
  }

  nav {
    padding: 0;
  }

  nav li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #330000;
  }

  nav a {
    display: block;
  }

  nav ul { 
    border: 2px solid #000000; 
  }

  #homehero {
    background-image: none;
    height: 0;
  }

  #yurthero {
    background-image: none;
    height: 0;
  }

  #trailhero {
    background-image: none;
    height: 0;
  }

  #mobile {
    display: inline;
  }

  #desktop {
    display: none;
  }

  label { 
    float: none;
    text-align: left; 
  }

  /*
  input[type="submit"] { 
    margin-left: 0; 
  }*/
}

form {
margin: 1.5rem 0;
}

form label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 120px;
}

form div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

form input:not(input[class="submit"]), form textarea {
  margin-left: .75rem;
}

form textarea {
  resize: vertical;
  width: 30ch;
  max-width: 40ch;
}

.submit {
  margin-left: 130px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset= "utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <Title>Pacific Trails Resort :: Reservations</Title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="pacific.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1> Pacific Trails Resort </h1>
      <meta name="description" content="Pacific Trails Resort reservations page.">
    </header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>  <li><a href="yurts.html">Yurts</a></li>  
        <li><a href="activities.html">Activities</a></li> 
        <li><a href="reservations.html">Reservations</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <h2>Reservations at Pacific Trails</h2>
      <h3>Contact Us Today!</h3>
      <form name="reservations" method="post" action="http://webdevbasics.net/scripts/pacific.php">
        <div>
          <label for="myFName">First Name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="myFName" id="myFName">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="myLName">Last Name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="myLName" id="myLName">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="myEmail">Email:</label>
          <input type="email" name="myEmail" id="myEmail" size="30">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="myPhone">Phone:</label>
          <input type="tel" name="myPhone" id="myPhone" maxlength="12">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="myComments">Comments:</label>
          <textarea name="myComments" id="myComments" rows="2" columns="30"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>

      <div id="contact">
        <span class="resort">Pacific Trails Resort</span> <br>
        12010 Pacific Trails Road <br>
        Zephyr, CA 95555 <br>
        <br>
        <a id="mobile" href="tel:888-555-5555">888-555-5555</a> <br>
        <span id="desktop">888-555-5555</span>
        <br>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
      Copyright © 2018 Pacific Trails Resort<br>
      <a href="mailto:e.sween12@gmail.com">e.sween12@gmail.com</a>
      </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for this, that helps. However, the field categories (first name, last name, etc.) are appearing above their respective entry fields if that makes sense? how do I get all of these elements on one line?

Comment: @ElizabethSweeney Your welcome! I updated my answer so the form fields are placed in row format with the label on the left and corresponding input next to it. Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: @ElizabethSweeney Feel free to mark my answer as accepted if it solved your problem.